# How can I dynamically update the array within a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, stack

So I have this struct

```
#define MAX 128

typedef struct this_struct {
Type items[MAX];
} *SVar;
```

Lets say we create something like this

```
SVar first = malloc(sizeof(struct this_struct));
```

Now when I push values into the array and it fills to the MAX which is 128, I need to dynamically create a new array but I don't know how since the array is inside.

Here are my current thoughts on how I want to do it:

- Create a new SVar names "second" with second->items[MAX *2]
- free(first)

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: use the pointer rather than an array. E.g `Type items[MAX];` chage to `Type *items;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY let's say I use a pointer. How does that change how I can manipulate its size?

Comment: `SVar second = malloc(sizeof(*second));second->items = malloc(sizeof(Type)*MAX*2);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What does sizeof(Type) do effectively? Returns the size of items?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can you see my update and help with this new issue

Comment: yes, return size of `Type`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It does, I forgot to add it sorry. It still crashes

Comment: `s = &second;` : type of `s` is `SVar`. but type of `&second` is `SVar*`.should be `s = second;` also  release `s` before assign.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY SVar is: typedef struct this_struct *SVar;

Comment: yes, I know. type of `second` is `SVar`. So type of `&second` is `SVar*`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So I go "second->items = s->items;second = s;" ? how can i get the first into the second and free the first?

Comment: There is a need to `realloc` if you take over the `items`. Otherwise you need to release.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How would I go about doing that? I never learned realloc

Comment: E.g `second->items = realloc(s->items, sizeof(Type)*MAX*2);` <-- When `realloc` is succeed, `items` is expanded to the new size leaving the contents.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So lets say I want the items in s to be of a new size to handle double I can go    "s->items = realloc(s->items, sizeof(Type)*MAX*2);"     instead and then I won't need to use second?

Comment: Of course it is possible to continue to use as it is Without using the new variable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That worked! Thank you. I understand malloc now. Also, basically since I am only altering the size of items I only need to allocate new memory for the size of the item and not the struct as a whole right?

Comment: It would be the easy operation to hold the size as a member of the structure.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I appreciate it thank you. I didn't know you could allocate specific members on top of the struct as a whole as separate things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do that is make your struct contain three values: first, a pointer to an array of  variables, and second a count of the currently allocated array size, and in practice, you will need a third item to track the number of array slots you're actually using.

So, with your struct, it would be something like this:

```
Type *items;
int item_length; /* Number allocated */
int item_count;  /* Number in use */
```

you initially allocate a "batch" of entries, say 100:

```
first = malloc(sizeof(this_struct));
first->items = malloc(sizeof(Type) * 100);
first->item_length = 100;
first->item_count = 0;
```

Then you add items one at a time. Simplistically, it's this:

```
first->items[first->item_count] = new_item;
first->item_count += 1;
```

But really you need to make sure each time you're not going to overflow the currently-allocated space, so it's *really* like this:

```
if (first->item_count == first->item_length) {
   first->item_length += 100;
   first->items = realloc(first->items, sizeof(Type) * first->item_length);
}
first->items[first->item_count] = new_item;
first->item_count += 1;
```

You're basically just using slots one at a time as long as your currently allocated space is large enough. Once you've used all the space you've allocated, realloc will either extend the array in place if there is room in the address space, or it will find and allocate a new larger space and move all the existing data to the new spot (and freeing up the old space).

In practice, you should check the return valueon the malloc and realloc calls.

Comment: From top to bottom, labeling your code snippets as steps from 1-4: Can step 3-4 be used inside a push function to push a new value on top of the stack?

Comment: Also what is the sizeof(Type) doing? Could I just use an initial sizeof(100)?

Comment: The argument to malloc is the number of bytes to allocate. Most types are larger than 1 byte in length so you need to allocate N bytes per item. That's what "sizeof(Type)" gives you: how many bytes are needed per item of that type.

Answer (score 0):

A usual trick is to do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int max_items; /* enough memory allocated for so many items */
    ...
    Whatever_type items[1]; /* must be the last member */
} Dyn_array;
...
int n = 127;
Dyn_array *p = malloc(sizeof(Dyn_array) + n*sizeof(p.items[0]);
p->max_items = n + 1;
...
n = 1023;
p = realloc(p, sizeof(Dyn_array) + n*sizeof(p.items[0]);
p->max_items = n + 1;
```

and so on. The code using the structure performs out-of-bound reads and writes to the `items` array, which is declared to store one item only. This is OK, however, since C does not do any bounds checking, and the memory allocation policy must guarantee that there is always enough space available for `num_items` items.